# How to resize image using canvas frame in python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Here I am trying to display images using the canvas frame but it is not showing anything.
what is wrong in this.
when I replace the frame with root in Label widget it is working.
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.title("Title")
root.geometry('600x600')

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image = photo)    
    label.image = photo 
def on_configure(event):

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

scrollbary = Scrollbar(root, orient = tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(root,orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,yscrollcommand = scrollbary.set,
                       xscrollcommand = scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=canvas.yview)
scrollbarx.config(command=canvas.xview)

scrollbary.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y',expand = tk.FALSE)

scrollbarx.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill = 'x',expand = tk.FALSE)

canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5,
                                                 fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

image = Image.open('logo1.png')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(frame, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to bind `<Configure>` to `label`.  Try calling `resize_image()` inside `on_configure()` function.